# how to convert div data into array using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to convert this code into an array.

```
<div id="Parent">
     <div class="childOne" ><span id="1dfgdffsf">ChildOne </span></div>
     <div class="childOne" ><span id = "2sdfsf">ChildTwo</span> </div>
     <div class="childOne" ><span id="3sdfsf">ChildThree </span></div>
     <div class="childOne" ><span id="4dssfsf">ChildFour </span></div>
</div>
```

span id is dynamic. therefore i can't use it.please tell me how to convert it into an array.

Comment: What result would you like to see as element of an array?

Comment: Also, "this" is not code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to loop over each element and push it into an array

```
//declare an array
var my_array = new Array();

//get all instances of the SPAN tag and iterate through each one
$('div#parent div.childOne span').each(function(){

    //build an associative array that assigns the span's id as the array id
    //assign the inner value of the span to the array piece
    //the single quotes and plus symbols are important in my_array[''++'']
    my_array[''+$(this).attr('id')+''] = $(this).text();

    //this code assigns the values to a non-associative array
    //use either this code or the code above depending on your needs
    my_array.push($(this).text());

});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not use a library, the following should work fine:

```
var result = [], matches = document.querySelectorAll("#Parent span");
for (var i = 0, l = matches.length; i < l; i++) 
    result.push(matches[i].getAttribute("id"));
```

Else if the `document.querySelectorAll` function is not supported:

```
var result = [], parent = document.getElementByID("Parent");
for (var i = 0, l = parent.childNodes.length; i < l; i++) 
    result.push(parent.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].getAttribute("id"));
```

If you wanted to get key/value pairs instead you can do the following:

```
var result = [], matches = document.querySelectorAll("#Parent span");
for (var i = 0, l = matches.length; i < l; i++) 
    result[matches[i].getAttribute("id")] = matches[i].text;
```

With jQuery it is as simple as a single line of code:

```
var result = $("#Parent span").map(function() { return $(this).attr("id"); }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to avoid naming id's and classes from capital letters.
Then try this:

```
var arr = [];
$('#parent').children().each(function(){
  arr.push($(this).find('span').text());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is the best way currently

```
const array = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.childOne'));
```

Comment: That or `[...document.querySelectorAll(selector)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Below Code May be help you :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { color:red; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div>Third</div>
<div>Fourth</div>
<script>
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); // returns a nodeList
var arr = jQuery.makeArray(elems);
arr.reverse(); // use an Array method on list of dom elements
$(arr).appendTo(document.body);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be simple one, as :

```
jQuery(function($) {
var anArray = [];
$("#Parent").find("span").each(function(){
    anArray.push($(this).html());
});
alert(anArray);
});
```